# Check my proof of Rudin's RCA Theorem 1.40

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Theorem 1.40 Suppose $\mu(X) < \infty$, $f \in L^1(\mu)$, S is a closed set in the complex plane, and the averages $$A_E(f) = \frac{1}{\mu(E)} \int_E f \, d\mu$$ lie in S for every E $\in \sigma$-algebra M with $\mu(E)>0$. Then $f(x)\in S$ for almost all x $\in$ X.

My attempt is somewhat similar to the given proof, but there are some parts I find iffy.
Attempt: 
Suppose there exist element b $\in S^c$  s.t. $\mu(f^{-1}(C))>0$, where C is a ball in $S^c$ centered at b. Let $B = f^{-1}(C).$
Then $$A_B(f)=\frac{1}{\mu(B)}\int_B f\,d\mu$$$$ = \sup \int_B \frac{u^+}{\mu(B)}\,d\mu - \sup \int_B \frac{u^-}{\mu(B)}\,d\mu + i\, \sup \int_B \frac{v^+ }{\mu(B)}\,d\mu - i\,\sup \int_B \frac{v^-}{\mu(B)}\,d\mu$$$$= \sup \sum_{1\leq i}\alpha_{1,i} \frac{\mu(F_{1,i} \cap B)}{\mu(B)} -  \sup \sum_{1\leq i}\alpha_{2,i} \frac{\mu(F_{2,i} \cap B)}{\mu(B)}\\ + i\,\sup \sum_{1\leq i}\alpha_{3,i} \frac{\mu(F_{3,i} \cap B)}{\mu(B)} -i\,\sup \sum_{1\leq i}\alpha_{4,i} \frac{\mu(F_{4,i} \cap B)}{\mu(B)}  $$ 
since $\sup \sum_{1\leq i} \frac{\mu(F_i \cap B)}{\mu(B)} = 1$. 
Hence $A_B(f)$ lies in the convex hull of the values taken by f on set B and hence lies in C.
This contradicts $A_B(f) \in S$ since $C \subseteq S^c$.

Comment: Supremum of complex numbers does not make sense.

Comment: Would it work if I separated the 4 components?

Comment: Also,  $f$ is defined on the abstract measure space $X$, not on $\mathbb{C}$, so integrating $f$ over $B$ also doesn't make sense.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I've made the necessary corrections. So my doubts lie over whether the third equality is valid.

Comment: You're still integrating over $B$ and taking $\mu(B)$. $B$ is not (a priori) a subset of $X$, so $\mu(B)$ is not defined. Also: What's wrong with just accepting Rudin's proof? It's really clean.

Comment: Finally: The Lesbegue integral of a general integrable function is *not* defined to be the supremum of integrals of simple functions. That definition only holds for *positive* functions.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Thank you and I do accept Rudin's proof. But I'm hoping to understand complex integration better by considering an alternative, as messy as it may be. I've redefined B as f-inverse(C), so B is a subset of X, right? Also, I've separated the 2nd and 3rd equalities into 4 integrals, so it should be correct now?

Comment: It's not clear in your argument why your ${\alpha_{j,i}}$ must necessarily belong to $S^c$.

Comment: Ok, I believe that resolves all of my doubts. Thanks.